# MySQL general SET-UP

Tags: mysql, django

I am new to MySQL, and I got some general problems and thanks for any help:

My OS is MAC SnowLeopard, and when I type 'mysql' in terminal, I could successfully go into the mysql system, but, I have no rights to create databases:

```
mysql> create database A;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'a'
```

I tried command line 'mysql -u root', I got the following:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I was thinking that I may set up the username for the database, which made me not possible enter mysql using root as username?

Then I tried 'localhost' as username, which I guess or remember I set it or not, using the command 'mysql -u localhost', I could successfully logged in to mysql, but STILL, cannot create database,

```
mysql> create database a;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'a'
```

I am not sure:

1. why root not working;
2. weather I set up the username and password myself before...sorry...really have no memory now.
3. If I have set up the username as 'localhost' before, I cannot remember the password, therefore I have no rights to create database?
4. What should I do to recover the password, in the case of no root access?
5. If not possible, how to uninstall it? The PATH in .bash_profile for mysql is `/usr/local/mysql/bin`

I got a check: sudo port list installed | grep mysql

```
mysql5                         @5.1.65         databases/mysql5
mysql5                         @5.1.65         databases/mysql5
py26-mysql                     @1.2.3          python/py-mysql
```

does the mysql in /usr/local/mysql/bin refer to this one listed here?

***Edit***
The result of running ps -ef | grep mysql:

```
    0   107     1   0   0:00.01 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/XXX-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
   74   245   107   0   0:03.51 ??         0:18.35 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/XXX-MacBook-Pro.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/XXX-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
  501  3790   417   0   0:00.00 ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql
  501  3337  1271   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.01 mysql -u localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reset your root password. To do this, follow those simple steps:

- Stop MySQL: `sudo port unload mysql5-server`
- Start MySQL using `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
- Connect to MySQL: `mysql -uroot`
- Reset your MySQL password:

  - mysql> use mysql;
  - mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
  - mysql> flush privileges;
  - mysql> quit
- Stop MySQL again `sudo killall -9 mysqld_safe`
- Restart MySQL normally `sudo port load mysql5-server`
- Connect to MySQL: `mysql -uroot -p`

**EDIT**

Added commands to stop/start MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Could you elaborate on how to Stop MySQL, like using which command? And, './mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables' would be used for start MYSQL in safe mode? Thanks again, appreciate any elaboration :)

Comment: How did you install MySQL? Through the mysql.com download or did you install it through Macports (or something similar)?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Simon. BTW, how could I figure that out then? Sorry..I am really new here.

Comment: Do you have a MySQL panel in your System Preferences?

Comment: I checked whether the mysql comes from ports using command line stuff edited in original post.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I updated another error msg when I tried to stop MySQL using sudo port unload mysql5-server, maybe I was not installing the mysql5-server by MacPorts?

Comment: Please send me the results of `ps -ef | grep mysql`.

Comment: Edited on my original post :) BTW, any suggestions on learning command line stuff?

Comment: One more question: send the results of `ls -l /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep mysql`

Comment: Nothing comes out on this command line. the LaunchDaemons is a directory under /Library/

Comment: 245 - 0x10011d830.anonymous.mysqld

Comment: It looks like MySQL was started manually. Are you sure you don't have a MySQL icon in System Preferences?

Comment: No, I did not find it in System Preferences